Derive the 0-1 law from a functional equation of a martingale limit
I am trying to understand a proof given by Jabbour-Hattab in the paper "Martingales and Large Deviations for Binary Search Trees".
In this paper, we consider the limit of a non-negative martingale, denoted by $M(z)$, where $z$ can be taken as a real positive number, it is not really important at this part of the proof. The limit does exist almost surely, and in the proof we consider the case where it exists.
For this limit, we want to prove the 0-1 law, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(M(z)=0)=0$ or $\mathbb{P}(M(z)=0)=1$.
In the last step of the proof, we get the following equation
$\mathbb{E}(e^{-tM(z)})=\int_0^1\mathbb{E}(e^{-tzx^{2z-1}M(z)})\mathbb{E}(e^{-tz(1-x)^{2z-1}M(z)}) \ dx.$
From this, it follows for $t\to \infty$ that the equation becomes
$\mathbb{P}(M(z)=0)=(\mathbb{P}(M(z)=0))^2$,
which implies the 0-1 law. I understand why the zero law follows from the last equation, but I don't see why the last equation follows from the one before.
I thought about using the fact that if a non-negative random variable $Y$ satisfies $\mathbb{E}(Y)=0$, then $Y=0$ almost surely, but I didn't come further.
Any help would be appreciated.

For $z>0$ and $0<x<1$ you have
$$
\lim_{t\to+\infty}\Bbb E(e^{-tM(z)})=\lim_{t\to+\infty}\Bbb E(e^{-tzx^{2z-1}M(z)})=\lim_{t\to+\infty}\Bbb E(e^{-tz(1-x)^{2z-1}M(z)})=\Bbb P(M(z)=0).
$$
Therefore sending $t\to+\infty$ in your integral identity results in
$$
\Bbb P(M(z)=0)=\int_0^1 P(M(z)=0)\cdot P(M(z)=0)\,dx =P(M(z)=0)^2,
$$
by the dominated convergence theorem.
You might also interpret the Laplace transform identity as saying that $M(z)$ has the same distribution as
$$
zU^{2z-1}M_1(z)+z(1-U)^{2z-1}M_2(z),
$$
in which $U, M_1(z), M_2(z)$ are mutually independent, $U$ in uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, and $M_1(z)$ and $M_2(z)$ have the same distribution as $M(z)$. Now notice that the just-displayed sum vanishes if and only if both $M_1(z)=0$ and $M_2(z)=0$.

Why do we have the equation $\lim_{t \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(e^{-tM(z)})=\mathbb{P}(M(z)=0)$?

Because $M(z)\ge 0$, as $t\to+\infty$ the r.v. $e^{-tM(z)}$ decreases to $0$ on ${M(z)>0}$ while maintaining the value $1$ on ${M(z)=0}$. In other words, $\lim_{t\to+\infty}e^{-tM(z)} =1_{{M(z)=0}}$. The expectation assertion follows by dominated (or monotone) convergence.

Ah, right, thanks a lot!
